# Help on non-linear mixed effect modeling approach?

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model

I am dealing with the following data frame:

```
GroupID Month Year   Concession_10Yr  Action  Historical_Action_5Yr
XY1       12   1984     1                0                 0
...
```

Here `GroupID` is a unique identifier for an organization. Then we have data every ear and month on whether the organization took "action", whether there was a "concession" (think "treatment") to this organization over the past 10 years and then whether the organization took action over the last 5 years.

What I'm trying to do is model the probability of an organization taking action. Clearly I can't do a simple linear regression as the organizations would be correlated with one another as some organizations are more likely to take action then others.

As such, I was thinking of a non-linear mixed effects model, something like:

```
lmer(Action ~ GroupID + Historical_Action_5Yr + Concession_10Yr +
     1/GroupID/Concession_10Yr + 1/GroupID/Historical_Action_5Yr, 
     family = binomial(link = logit)
```

However, I am not sure that I have the nesting correct. Also, this doesn't account for time directly...

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [paper](ftp://www.postfix.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CRAN/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) about the package, the `(1 | g1/g2)` (or the equivalent `(1 | g1)+(1 | g1:g2)`) notation means:

> Intercept varying among g1 and g2 within g1

Thus your model consists of the following parts:

- A fixed effect for `GroupID`
- A fixed effect for `Historical_Action_5Yr`
- A fixed effect for `Concession_10Yr`
- An intercept varying for `GroupID` and an intercept for `Concession_10Yr` withing `GroupID`, noted as `(1 | GroupID/Concession_10Yr)`
- An intercept for `GroupID` and an intercept for `Historical_Action_5Yr` within `GroupID`, noted as `(1 | GroupID/Historical_Action_5Yr)`. Since there is already an intercept varying for `GroupID` you could also use `(1 | GroupID:Historical_Action_5Yr)` to compute the intercept for all combinations of `GroupID` and `Historical_Action_5Yr`.

In short:

```
lmer(Action ~ GroupID + Historical_Action_5Yr + Concession_10Yr + (1 |GroupID/Concession_10Yr) + (1 | GroupID:Historical_Action_5Yr), family = binomial(link =logit)
```

Comment: Hi Pieter: That's the thing, I'm not quite sure I need all combinations of GroupID & Historical_Action_5YR -- I'm looking for some help on how the model should be?

Comment: There no such thing as a correct answer on that. You should think about what you think the relations are like. The data could also guide you to an answer. Start by learning a simple model and check the coefficients and error distribution. If the latter it is normally distributed and the spread is small enough, you're done :) If not, include additional variable (interactions) and check if they make sense (correct direction?) and if they add something.